# Vagrant with ansible stop when meet console questions

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, ansible

I'm installing mongo extension for PHP in my vagrant with this task

```
---
- name: Intall MongoDb PHP extension
  sudo: yes
  command: "pecl install mongo"

- name: Copy mongo extension INI to mods-available folder
  template: >
    src=mongodb_extension.ini.j2
    dest={{ php_conf_dir }}/mongodb.ini
    owner=root group root mode=644
- name: Enabling mongo config in PHP cli conf
  sudo: yes
  file: src={{ php_conf_dir }}/xhprof.ini  dest=/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini state=link

- name: Enabling xhprof config in PHP fpm conf
  sudo: yes
  file: src={{ php_conf_dir }}/xhprof.ini  dest=/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini state=link
  notify: reload php-fpm
```

The problem is it stucks at this **Intall MongoDb PHP extension**

I tried install mongo extension manually and see that the console asks this question **Build with Cyrus SASL (MongoDB Enterprise Authentication) support? [no] :**

I think the problem is this question.

Does anybody know how to answer this question in ansible, so it can run provision?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer the prompt with `yes` or `yes yes` (if you want to reply 'yes') or `yes no` (if you want to reply no).

So, you can make your task like so:

```
- name: Intall MongoDb PHP extension
  sudo: yes
  shell: "yes {{ php_install_mongo }} | pecl install mongo"
```

And set `php_install_mongo` somewhere (or remove the var, and set it to a fixed value).

Note that it will reply the same answer to all questions (but it is not relevant in this case AFAIK).

**EDIT**: There is a better looking alternate way using thee-lesser-than operator:

```
- name: Intall MongoDb PHP extension
  sudo: yes
  shell: "pecl install mongo <<< '{{ php_install_mongo }}'"
```